# Meaningless Y-axis values in ggplot2 dot plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis

I am trying to replicate [Fivethirtyeight's Tarantino movie plot](http://fivethirtyeight.com/features/complete-catalog-curses-deaths-quentin-tarantino-films/). This plot is using ggplot2's `dotplot`. The data can be found [here](https://github.com/fivethirtyeight/data/tree/master/tarantino).

My code is following:

```
tara <- read.csv("tarantino.csv")
dim(tara)
names(tara)
table(tara$movie)

rd <- subset(tara, movie=="Reservoir Dogs")
du <- subset(tara, movie=="Django Unchained")
ib <- subset(tara, movie=="Inglorious Basterds") 
jb <- subset(tara, movie=="Jackie Brown")
kb1 <- subset(tara, movie=="Kill Bill: Vol. 1")
kb2 <- subset(tara, movie=="Kill Bill: Vol. 2")
pf <- subset(tara, movie=="Pulp Fiction")



plot1 <- ggplot(rd, aes(x=minutes_in, fill=type)) +
  geom_dotplot(binwidth=0.5, method="histodot") +
  theme_bw() + theme(legend.position="none") +
  ylim(0,20)+
  # Set the entire chart region to a light gray color
  theme(panel.background=element_rect(fill="#F0F0F0")) +
  theme(plot.background=element_rect(fill="#F0F0F0")) +
  theme(panel.border=element_rect(colour="#F0F0F0")) +
  ggtitle(" RESERVIOR DOGS") +
  theme(plot.title=element_text(face="bold",hjust=-.08,vjust=2,colour="#535353",size=12)) +
  ylab("") +
  xlab("")
plot2 <- ggplot(pf, aes(x=minutes_in, fill=type)) +
  geom_dotplot(binwidth=0.5, method="histodot") +
  theme_bw() +theme(legend.position="top")+
  ylim(0,20)+
  # Set the entire chart region to a light gray color
  theme(panel.background=element_rect(fill="#F0F0F0")) +
  theme(plot.background=element_rect(fill="#F0F0F0")) +
  theme(panel.border=element_rect(colour="#F0F0F0")) +
  theme(legend.position="none")  +
  ggtitle(" PULP FICTION") +
  theme(plot.title=element_text(face="bold",hjust=-.08,vjust=2,colour="#535353",size=12)) +
  ylab("") +
  xlab("")
plot3 <- ggplot(du, aes(x=minutes_in, fill=type)) +
  geom_dotplot(binwidth=0.5, method="histodot") +
  theme_bw() +theme(legend.position="top")+
  ylim(0,20)+
  # Set the entire chart region to a light gray color
  theme(panel.background=element_rect(fill="#F0F0F0")) +
  theme(plot.background=element_rect(fill="#F0F0F0")) +
  theme(panel.border=element_rect(colour="#F0F0F0")) +
  theme(legend.position="none")  +
  ggtitle(" DJANGO UNCHAINED") +
  theme(plot.title=element_text(face="bold",hjust=-.08,vjust=2,colour="#535353",size=12)) +
  ylab("") +
  xlab("")

plot4 <- ggplot(ib, aes(x=minutes_in, fill=type)) +
  geom_dotplot(binwidth=0.5, method="histodot") +
  theme_bw() +theme(legend.position="top")+
  ylim(0,20)+
  # Set the entire chart region to a light gray color
  theme(panel.background=element_rect(fill="#F0F0F0")) +
  theme(plot.background=element_rect(fill="#F0F0F0")) +
  theme(panel.border=element_rect(colour="#F0F0F0")) +
  theme(legend.position="none")  +
  ggtitle(" INGLORIOUS BASTARDS") +
  theme(plot.title=element_text(face="bold",hjust=-.08,vjust=2,colour="#535353",size=12)) +
  ylab("") +
  xlab("")

plot5 <- ggplot(jb, aes(x=minutes_in, fill=type)) +
  geom_dotplot(binwidth=0.5, method="histodot") +
  theme_bw() +theme(legend.position="top")+
  ylim(0,20)+
  # Set the entire chart region to a light gray color
  theme(panel.background=element_rect(fill="#F0F0F0")) +
  theme(plot.background=element_rect(fill="#F0F0F0")) +
  theme(panel.border=element_rect(colour="#F0F0F0")) +
  theme(legend.position="none")  +
  ggtitle(" JACKIE BROWN") +
  theme(plot.title=element_text(face="bold",hjust=-.08,vjust=2,colour="#535353",size=12)) +
  ylab("") +
  xlab("")

plot6 <- ggplot(kb1, aes(x=minutes_in, fill=type)) +
  geom_dotplot(binwidth=0.5, method="histodot") +
  theme_bw() +theme(legend.position="top")+
  ylim(0,20)+
  # Set the entire chart region to a light gray color
  theme(panel.background=element_rect(fill="#F0F0F0")) +
  theme(plot.background=element_rect(fill="#F0F0F0")) +
  theme(panel.border=element_rect(colour="#F0F0F0")) +
  theme(legend.position="none")  +
  ggtitle(" KILL BILL: VOL 1") +
  theme(plot.title=element_text(face="bold",hjust=-.08,vjust=2,colour="#535353",size=12)) +
  ylab("") +
  xlab("")

plot7 <- ggplot(kb2, aes(x=minutes_in, fill=type)) +
  geom_dotplot(binwidth=0.5, method="histodot") +
  theme_bw() +theme(legend.position="none")+
  ylim(0,20)+
  # Set the entire chart region to a light gray color
  theme(panel.background=element_rect(fill="#F0F0F0")) +
  theme(plot.background=element_rect(fill="#F0F0F0")) +
  theme(panel.border=element_rect(colour="#F0F0F0")) +
  ggtitle(" KILL BILL: VOL 2") +
  theme(plot.title=element_text(face="bold",hjust=-.08,vjust=2,colour="#535353",size=12)) +
  ylab("") +
  xlab("minutes")





library(grid)
grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(7, 1)))
vplayout <- function(x, y)
  viewport(layout.pos.row = x, layout.pos.col = y)
print(plot1, vp = vplayout(1, 1))
print(plot2, vp = vplayout(2, 1))
print(plot3, vp = vplayout(3, 1))
print(plot4, vp = vplayout(4, 1))
print(plot5, vp = vplayout(5, 1))
print(plot6, vp = vplayout(6, 1))
print(plot7, vp = vplayout(7, 1))
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

The plot has several issues:

- Y axis is uncontrollable. I can use `coord_fixed(ratio=X)`; but it's not helping much.
- The dots are not same size. I have tried to use `dotsize`; but it's not working.
- Failed to keep background `grey` in the legends.

Comment: Your code is not very DRY. Use `facet_grid`, and ggplot will keep scales consistent. It does have a different look, though, which you might need to work to force into what you want.

Comment: @alistaire what does 'DRY' mean. It look very similar to my code :P Agree with you about `facet_grid`.

Comment: What do you mean with uncontrollable y axis? You set the limits yourself...

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself). Your code is at least 7 times as long as it should be; use `movie` in `facet_grid` to reduce repetition. Or at least write a plotting function.

Comment: Also, I think you mean the x-axis, not y, and you don't have any legends showing, so I'm not sure how the background is off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an approach:

```
# download data
download.file('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fivethirtyeight/data/master/tarantino/tarantino.csv', '~/Desktop/tarantino.csv', method = 'curl')

# read in data
tara <- read.csv('~/Desktop/tarantino.csv')

library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)     # has theme_fivethirtyeight, which will save a lot of work

ggplot(tara, aes(x=minutes_in, fill=type)) +
  geom_dotplot(binwidth = 1, method = "histodot") +
  theme_fivethirtyeight() + 
  ylim(0, 20) +
  ggtitle('Deaths and Swearing in Tarantino Films') +
  theme(strip.text = element_text(hjust = 0)) +     # left justify facet titles
  ylab("") +
  xlab("") + 
  # facet_wrap defaults to titles on top. The labeller capitalizes movie titles.
  facet_wrap(~movie, ncol = 1, labeller = labeller(movie = toupper))

# bin width/dot size is CRAZY SENSITIVE to aspect ratio. width 4:height 5:binwidth 1 lines up with your y-axis
ggsave('~/Desktop/Rplot.png', width = 8, height = 10, units = 'in')
```

What you get:

[image: dotplot of Tarantino films]

Comment: Thanks. While trying to replicate, I have the following error message: `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) :  Theme element 'text' has NULL property: margin, debug
In addition: Warning message: 'axis.ticks.margin' is deprecated. Please set 'margin' property  of 'axis.text' instead `. I have updated `ggthemes` package; but I am getting the same error.

Comment: Odd. What version of `ggplot2` are you using? There were some major changes in the 2.0.0 version that came out in December that might be causing the issue.

Comment: From `sessionInfo()`: `R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.11 (El Capitan)` and `ggplot2_2.0.0` and `ggthemes_3.0.1`.

Comment: Using `ggplot2_1.0.1` from another PC, I am getting this error: `Error in facet_wrap(~movie, ncol = 1, labeller = labeller(movie = toupper)) : 
  unused argument (labeller = labeller(movie = toupper))`.

Comment: Now it's working after deleting `labeller = labeller(movie = toupper)` in `ggplot2_1.0.1`.

Comment: I'm using the ggplot2 2.0.0 and ggthemes 3.0.1 on OS X 10.11, too, so I don't think it's a version issue. It sounds like the data has null values for `movie`; try downloading and loading like above (change the paths if you like), and see if that fixes it.

Comment: You can also try `labeller = as_labeller(toupper)` or just changing the original values with `tara$movie <- toupper(tara$movie)` before you plot.